# Language selection in website/browser for localized advertisment

Tags: javascript, php, browser

Unfortunately Amazon.com/.de do have separated partner-programs, so that there is no ready to use script for websites to switch their advertisements according to the IP address or the browser language selection.

So I would like to do that in PHP or in JS, but I don't know how to do that.
It starts hoe to get the language selection from the browser, and then I would like to ask what would be more flexible.

I would say that JavaScript would be more flexible because you can better switch it's code in case you have to alter something.

Could you give me some hints?

Comment: I don't understand; what does Amazon have to do with this issue?

Comment: it has partner-programms for all their international markets, like .de .fr .nl and have their own specific ads. but they don't deifferentiate between where the user comes from. so if you are from the netherlands on a site with german amazon ads you will be presented with german amazon products, but as a dutch person you prefer buying from amazon.nl. so I would like to display ads according to their ip-address

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use `navigator.userLanguage` and `navigator.language` in JavaScript to do this. There is a small example at [Java2s.com](http://www.java2s.com/Code/JavaScript/Window-Browser/Verifybrowserlanguage.htm)

If you want to do this via php, use `$_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'];`.